# Download multiple files .NET CORE Web API as ArchiveZip return root directory

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core

I make a private class to get the bytes of the file and then return it into a zip file. Basically, I just want to pick specific files inside my folder and then zip it then download it. Here's my class:

```
private FileResult DownloadMultipleFiles(List<byte[]> byteArrayList)
        {
            var zipName = $"archive-EvidenceFiles-{DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy_MM_dd-HH_mm_ss")}.zip";
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (var archive = new ZipArchive(ms, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
                {
                    foreach (var file in byteArrayList)
                    {
                        string fPath = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(file);
                        var entry = archive.CreateEntry(fPath, CompressionLevel.Fastest);
                        using (var zipStream = entry.Open())
                        {
                            zipStream.Write(file, 0, file.Length);
                        }
                    }
                }
                return File(ms.ToArray(), "application/zip", zipName);
            }
        }
```

And then, here's my controller:

```
[HttpGet("GetBundleFiles/{rhaId}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetBundleFiles(string rhaId)
        {
            List<byte[]> filesPath = new List<byte[]>();
            var results = await _rhaFileEvidence.GetByRhaID(rhaId);
            var files = results.ToList();
            if (files.Count == 0)
                return Ok(new { status = "null", message = "Empty data" });

            files.ForEach(file =>
            {
                var fPath = file.FilePath;
                byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(fPath);
                filesPath.Add(bytes);
            });

            return DownloadMultipleFiles(filesPath);
        }
```

The controller works well, I can download the zip but when I open it, I can't get the files instead I get the root directory of the project I saved, like `D:`. I think I make mistake when making the memory stream or something, is there any suggestion how can I fix this? (Paste some solution code in the answer please)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are getting the directory root because when you use `archive.CreateEntry` you are passing the file full path in parameter, you should be using only the file name

`var entry = archive.CreateEntry(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fPath), CompressionLevel.Fastest);`

a second issue is that you actually saving the file path to your files not the content of the original file. you can update your DownloadMultipleFiles like this

```
private FileResult DownloadMultipleFiles(List<byte[]> byteArrayList)
{
     var zipName = $"archive-EvidenceFiles-{DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy_MM_dd-HH_mm_ss")}.zip";
      using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
      {
         using (var archive = new ZipArchive(ms, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
         {
             foreach (var file in byteArrayList)
             {
                string fPath = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(file);
                var entry = archive.CreateEntry(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fPath), CompressionLevel.Fastest);
                using (var zipStream = entry.Open())
                {
                    var bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fPath);
                    zipStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                }
             }
          }
         return File(ms.ToArray(), "application/zip", zipName);
      }
 }
```

Comment: `var bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fPath)` this line throws "Illegal characters in path. (Parameter 'path')"